# Android Disable ActionBarSherlock Top Icon Click

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've been searching for a way to disable the top icon click in the action bar for ABSherlock. Settting this `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` doesnt seems to work either. Currently my top icon click is clickable, it highlights the whole icon whenever you tap on it. I do not want a go back functionality, I just want it not clickable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean))

> Enable or disable the "home" button in the corner of the action bar. (Note that this is the application home/up affordance on the action bar, not the systemwide home button.)
>
> This defaults to true for packages targeting < API 14. For packages targeting API 14 or greater, the application should call this method to enable interaction with the home/up affordance.
>
> Setting the `DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP` display option will automatically enable the home button.

Comment: I've got another question regarding changing actionbarsherlock text font. Will open a new question